# Set terminal window title in a script

Tags: terminal, bash, script

I would like to change the entire title of the terminal window for a particular bash script. I googled out but I couldn't find much more than this suggestion:

```
printf "\e]0;My Custom Title\a"
```

After running the line above, my terminal window's title becomes so:

**ft1 — My Custom Title — bash — 80×24**

But I would like it to become just like this:

**My Custom Title**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Open the preferences for Terminal and untick the following flags

[image]

If this alone doesn't solve the problem

- `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`
- check whether PS1 (the prompt string) changes the window title as well

Comment: Actually I was looking for something that only affects the terminal that is running the script, not the global settings. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: You can create a new profile and assign this to the terminal tab/window in question.